# ncal command question find number of Mondays

Tags: bash, zsh

how can I find the number of Mondays that falls on the first of each month in a given year with the cal command.
I've tried so far grepping each line that contains Mo

```sh
ncal 2021 | grep Mo
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for outsourcing homework. I answered because the task was fun. However, I hope you know why homework is assigned and that you just ruined your chance to learn so much more than just understanding other people's ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple in the ncal format. Here is the output of `ncal 2012`:

```
                              2012
    January           February          March             April
Su  1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26        4 11 18 25     1  8 15 22 29
Mo  2  9 16 23 30        6 13 20 27        5 12 19 26     2  9 16 23 30
Tu  3 10 17 24 31        7 14 21 28        6 13 20 27     3 10 17 24
We  4 11 18 25        1  8 15 22 29        7 14 21 28     4 11 18 25
Th  5 12 19 26        2  9 16 23        1  8 15 22 29     5 12 19 26
Fr  6 13 20 27        3 10 17 24        2  9 16 23 30     6 13 20 27
Sa  7 14 21 28        4 11 18 25        3 10 17 24 31     7 14 21 28

    May               June              July              August
Su     6 13 20 27        3 10 17 24     1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26
Mo     7 14 21 28        4 11 18 25     2  9 16 23 30        6 13 20 27
Tu  1  8 15 22 29        5 12 19 26     3 10 17 24 31        7 14 21 28
...
```

How would you solve the task by hand?

- Look only at the lines starting with `Mo`
- In those lines, search for `1`.
- Write down the total number of found `1`s.

These three steps correspond to the following three commands after `ncal`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
year=$1
ncal "$year" | grep '^Mo' | grep -wo 1 | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice one ! I wonder how easy (or hard) is it to process `cal` output, or if they put more strict constaints like you can not even use external program like grep.

Comment: @Philippe Only slightly harder to implement, but way harder to explain because of the regex: `LC_ALL=POSIX cal 1951 | grep -Eo '(^|[0-9]  )    1\b' | wc -l`. The regex assumes weeks to start on Sunday, therefore the `LC_ALL` is recommended.

Comment: great ! the only thing I would say is that `\b' may not be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the `\b` is indeed not necessary. I compared the results for the years 1700 to 2100. However, better be safe than sorry :)

Comment: Absolutely ! Final question : what value of LC_ALL makes `cal` not starting with Sunday ? Or I have to read man pages :-)

Comment: There are many locals in which Monday is the first day of the week, for instance German. However, to try this you need that locale on your system. `LC_ALL=en_DK cal` is an example that might be a bit more available than German. BTW: `ncal` offers the options `-M` and `-S` to set the first day of the week. Therefore, if you are just forced to use the old `cal` format, you could use `ncal -Sb 2021` too.